# How I can interface the MCU without soldering?

Tags: hardware, router

My router has the following pin layout between flash memory and MCU:

[image: Flash memory chip and MCU]

The big chip is the MCU from a Sercomm H300s router.

What I want is to analyze the signaling between 2 chips using the most accessible pins in the MCU. But I also want to avoid soldering.

How I can interface the big chip without soldering?
Would clamps such as these [ones](https://www.ebay.com/itm/323746586348?epid=15024242833&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item4b60ccdeec:g:Z7QAAOSwPnthK-BZ&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAACkPYe5NmHp%252B2JMhMi7yxGiTJkPrKr5t53CooMSQt2orsSvhAqMt0wg86xg8aAkgjQJEesUdG49X%252FpjIjVTJN1GR1pS1RG16tFMf9utYqIlM524JGnHig3woQUDmErs0mW2C6Mdq2gEcfdvdhN%252B62xJ1T0nQWdfxu4xyMm5952oI7DS1YiY3QjrKT5h0c1RCUNlA%252Bk8wNEIbnpsiCeRwP5mXPxqTfYrSxqeXBptqSARALQ3fHwPqhp0IL9SFzq4nLiJlQWOQEbQbmMDvu4swjFCAIjRszwgS7Mzd2woxtifRhw7IBwXIRghpuMCyE6iXLjqccv0bBknRZSBRF%252B7Dxf63qfPxo9VNpyT299WcwQi358S2Pl5ig%252Fes8zuK2oY2LrkPNyJqXynU3LAQmExd%252BUYwlsrq33Eg6rbTWTuHPu0TGodFy3AOpOKfFDrn4kjj7F%252B0%252FyfIiEms9jQ8fcBlUf6dFWD928aRj6h4rwrjXsj7F6jULrlwEiJmXthQHeqloO0G2uC%252FCoGbdX91yjTsA7BUtHCPyz6jl1bFem%252BZp2UjEOHQ68abCMJ9bwLu8D1fjiAf9gVKBj5WWv2Cz1%252FlZsWLwGT%252FI1owiZweN%252Bwd2YgHoa9RGIx8XfwmVp9RPzmCpMpNkFDzojZHincUcDNsUPc1ZpllG7rQvW%252FEGGorc42Gr%252BbB%252BIQtEbRlPmDWc9y2QOjMWBj7%252FHFUNMmVqx25t2Jd%252B%252FqL5DFTA3r3ZPF6yKvi5XkbmWxHcQeiQY7lRj%252BgNszG3Qg4im43gOYburrxqb1rdJk5JWuvkPf95Tnrw0W26wu2Ry5Gph%252F%252BxKgnXFT2smd5YJ3ikt%252BX1yVi7AxK79OBCBkHcB%252BaGTaQqqEkN%252FK%252BaA%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524) or this [ones](https://www.ebay.com/itm/133847400004?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item1f29ed3e44:g:iYwAAOSwzMphFlJB&amdata=enc%3AAQAGAAACoPYe5NmHp%252B2JMhMi7yxGiTJkPrKr5t53CooMSQt2orsSHYXPhGXR5uguexJBeHwfgVsesCgic2L9x99OPJIQsKTVY61B1ywsPShm%252Ftgp1YhD6%252BrSqMb7%252Ffa1rLe7%252B99XQXSpckzbr6topVUZHiRWlUnsKRAfMsp5KVokNZu%252Ff%252FHa3JV%252Bj9%252FwEdsafUbv4Pr%252BjN30QrMRxIi%252FpjFfSba3MsZ2agYDO1A3hpNyvAzY78AyoxisOs7tuCA3tgOf4Gtr26wLWXx90Fc%252BrWGXqUHRY8cd1YOT5%252Fer7r45gfYbOr9SCxBcYRtZqbSgJXYhYoV82ICbRUXrZzOGKpsFsZEVAGfOMuoeZiTa2WY9iVnadhDJLf6AyGN7XAivIKgDnqlNm0f9GmL16LrUoFVcVXt4GFvmKKZnRr0xOiE%252FnzMK8OpFlL9xlRBPrmeCTnTcQafDsUvAdsfWeWVuzOD9JikYhcZ8JzFwvHMDNPUcunIstvrAvXsFqCivsL93vjX66subXcm3%252BJZIyBvAHQX2B287N0TRp5qHwD6nWepRzYDTxokqlJbSPEKLJ7HyK3uI3NPtDwxeHOYn4j0gIx%252Ft4rjZzQm%252FHyJgVIc2i5FbMo6tGoUuhUeMmdqmRHh5QQ1oPAYvWmS0mTt8Bhd6jedhGRYoV6tQghmmNJWwnUOURzI95UXfa5SkziPdei36E2x6p16mOO58PcANo1UfNuNs0XrsGs9WpAMyOz4Pqk6toCqnP%252B3COhJV3Gw13lQw3NSBnmRKsUQouFHh7EjLYMw2AhVqaj%252FMeJYm0xNK4bMue%252BVK3DULipUVhE4QEgvyCfOCDXXnqPB6rbmh15jg9qbm4ZORmyc%252FGE%252BGhrh%252FIdzMF3orXP8n8Cflida61%252FxtLR2WP7GEOg%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2334524) do the job?

Also, how I can record any binary data exchanged between MCU and Flash memory chip in my computer, do I need a bus pirate or a logic analyzer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/